# How to delete a Git remote tag named @

Tags: git, github, git-tag

Accidentally I created and pushed a Git tag named `@` onto GitHub.

```
git tag -a -s @ 
git push --tags
```

Now I want to get rid of this tag again. GitHub offers no UI to delete a Git tag. I succeeded to delete the local tag, but regardless what I try, I failed to push-delete the remote tag. This is what I tried already:

```
$ git push :@                                                                                                                                    
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
$ git push :"@" 
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
$ git push --delete origin "@"                                                                                                               
fatal: invalid Refspec ':@'
$ git push --delete origin \@    
fatal: invalid Refspec ':\@'
$ git push --delete origin '@'   
fatal: invalid Refspec ':@'
```

Anybody a hint what should to the trick?

Comment: Yikes. Git should have forbid that name. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format says that a ref cannot be "@" by itself; "tags/@" of course isn't, but it contains "@" as a component, which should really be forbidden. Might be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: Thanks @torek for the pointer! I'm writing a question/bug report to the Git mailing list right now.

Answer (score 2):

Meh! Found it out after browsing the `.gif/refs` directory:

```
git push --delete origin tags/@
```

does the trick.